# React Redux TypeError this.props.setEmailText is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

React Redux TypeError this.props.setEmailText is not a function. Is it the bindind issue, as when i get the props by {...this.props} all is good ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/reduxex1-f9sid

```
import React from "react";

export default class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  onEmailChange(e) {
    this.props.setEmailText(e.target.value);
  }

  onPasswordChange(e) {
    this.props.setPasswordText(e.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share how you are passing the props to `<Auth />` component? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `this.props.setEmailText` to `onEmailChange` prop of `Auth` component, `onEmailChange={this.props.setEmailText}`. Change to use a consistent prop name.

```
class AuthContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Auth
        email={this.props.email}
        password={this.props.password}
        setEmailText={this.props.setEmailText} // <-- use setEmailText
        setPasswordText={this.props.setPasswordText}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now `Auth` can access the prop

```
onEmailChange(e) {
  this.props.setEmailText(e.target.value);
}
```